# Update query not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a simple IP banning script in PHP and MySQL, and I am at the stage of creating the edit ban page where they can modify the reason and the IP address. I have created an update query which will update that record in the database. I have a get request to collect the id like so:

`edit_banned_ip.php?id=1`

I then use a select statement to collect the information and set the variable `$id` which I then use in my update query below:

This is my query:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
  if ($_POST['ip'] != '' && $_POST['reason'] != '') {
    $ip = $_POST['ip'];
    $reason = $_POST['reason'];

    // run update query
    $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE `banned_ips` SET `ip` = ?, `reason` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
    $update->bind_param('ssi', $ip, $reason, $id);

    if ($update->execute()) {
      if ($update->affected_rows > 0) {
      $_SESSION['update_success'] = 'Success';
      }
    }
  }
}

 ?>
```

I am honestly puzzled as to what I am doing wrong, so if someone can see an issue with this query then that would make my day.

The issue I am having is the query does execute however no row is affected and the record doesn't update.

EDIT:

Thanks for those who have answered, I echoed the `$ip` variable and it was correct.

Below the above query I have this code (to grab the data):

```
<?php
    if ($_GET) {
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
    if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ip, reason FROM banned_ips WHERE id = ?")) {

   $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); 
   $stmt->execute(); 
   $stmt->bind_result($ip, $reason);

   while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    }
  }
?>
```

This is how I get the `$id` variable and the two $_POST variables are from the form.

Comment: Have you checked the values of your variables?

Comment: You're using a GET method `edit_banned_ip.php?id=1` with POST variables.

Comment: SQL text looks like valid syntax; we don't have enough information to check semantics (table name, column names, privileges, triggers, etc.). We don't see any value being assigned to the `$id` variable. For debugging, I recommend you **`echo $id;`** before the `bind_param`.

Comment: Well you're not declaring a variable for your `id` Try adding `$id=$_REQUEST['id'];` as well as an `isset`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited my question. This is how I grab my `$id` variable.

Comment: I recommend you don't do it that way. You're best to add `$id=$_REQUEST['id'];` under your `$reason = $_POST['reason'];` you're doing this with a form, right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- that works, thank you. I'll remember that in future :)

Comment: You're welcome. Shall I make it an answer to close the question? It's up to you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, it will give you 35 rep, 25 for the answer, 10 for a vote up :)

Comment: Ok, will do. @MattKent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're using a GET method `edit_banned_ip.php?id=1` with POST variables and you haven't defined the variable for `id` yet, only in your `bind_param` and that isn't enough.

I recommend you don't do it that way.

You're best to add `$id=$_REQUEST['id'];` under your `$reason = $_POST['reason'];`

Answer (score 0):

Variables that are defined on the URI are GET variables.

http://somewebsites.com?id=1
- You access it with $_GET['id']

Query looks good to me